# Accessors on a pivot table in many to many polymorphic

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a polymorphic relationship using a pivot table with some simple columns.

The pivot table has `created_at` and `updated_at`. Is there anyway I can set Accessors on those, so I can have them formatted in the collection without looping through it?

```
public function organization()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Organization', 'relationship')->withPivot('relationship_level')->withTimestamps();
}

public function regions()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Region', 'relationship')->withPivot('relationship_level')->withTimestamps();
}

public function groups()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Group', 'relationship')->withPivot('relationship_level')->withTimestamps();
}
```

This is the code. I want when I try to access ->pivot->created_at to get it formatted in human way.

Comment: Can you show a minimal code of your relationship?

Comment: Added the code of the main relationships.

Answer (score 0):

You can write an accessor on your polymorhic model, i.e.:

```
public function getFooAttribute()
{
    return $this->pivot ? $this->pivot->created_at->format('Y-m-d') : 'pivot not loaded';
}
```

And access with `$model->foo`.

Remember that `$model` should be loaded by its **Owner model** so you have the pivot loaded, i.e.:

```
Region::with('polymorphic_models')->find($id);
```

And you have to define `->withPivot('relationship_level')->withTimestamps();` on both sides of the relationship.

Comment: Please consider accepting and upvoting the answer if you find it useful